# File path encoding in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a small application which saves file paths to a database (using django). I assumed file paths are utf-8 encoded, but I ran into the following file name: `C:\FXG™.nfo` which is apparently not encoded in utf-8.

When I do `filepath.decode('utf-8')` I get the following error:

> `UnicodeDecodeError:` 'utf8' codec can't decode byte `0x99` in position 30: invalid start byte

(I trimmed the file name, so the position is wrong here).

How do I know how the file paths are encoded in a way that this will work for every file name?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`.

That should allow you to convert all paths that look ok.

However, there can always be illegally-encoded files or folders, you have to think how to deal with those in the framework of your application.

Some apps may ignore such files, others keep name as a binary blob.